# If statement for swapping class

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to try and swap a class only if a certain class name is present on the page;

```
$(function() { 
    if ($('.special').length){
        $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color").addClass("tab_item_color");
    }
});
```

So in English: If the class "special" is present, then remove .tab_item and add tab_item_color instead.

This is what I want it to do. Does this read correctly? Should swapClass be used?

Comment: *Does this read correct?* No, it doesn't. You're removing `tab_item_color`, not `tab_item`.

Comment: Typo? You're removing then adding the same class

Comment: Do you mean toggleClass() or jQueryUI's switchClass()? Maybe I'm not aware of swapClass() in jQuery

Comment: Have you tried it (typo aside)?  Does it do what you're expecting?  If not, what are you expecting and what does it do?

Comment: Use `hasClass` to check class name exists or not

Comment: Thank you hasClass is what i was thinking to use. the above statement was given in a post earlier today where i asked for help but never worked, but they kept telling me to mark it as correct. when i saw it as wrong.

Comment: Only mark it correct if it's correct...

Comment: @david, I have read that question, and you ask for a way to know if a class is present *in the document*. So apparently the answer is right, and the way you describe what you want is wrong.

Comment: If the class name "special" is present in the current document, then remove .tab_item class and swap with tab_item_color class.

Comment: what typo?, why say something and not reveal what you are talking about?

Comment: typo is as follows: "then remove `tab_item` and add `tab_item_color` instead" for this you should have code like `$(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item").addClass("tab_item_color");`

Comment: @vijayP I only posted what the previous "guru"s said amended what i did. and they just told me to mark it write and open a new thread if i needed more help. but there answer was correct. but there answer was not correct. So the code there is not a type, but well thought out by previous gurus say it is correct.

Comment: Why all the down marking of the question like its full of faults. i wrote the code that was presented to me and translated it into English, so you would understand what i require. I already challenged this faults with others who where so inclined that it was all perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code, you have to check `special` class is exist in element

```
$(function() { 
    $('.tab_item').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("special")){
             $(this).removeClass("tab_item").addClass("tab_item_color");
        }
    });
});
```

or

```
$(function() { 
    $('.tab_item.special').removeClass("tab_item").addClass("tab_item_color");
});
```

Comment: While the question is extremely unclear, it does state "*only if a certain class name is present on the page*" - not: if a class name is present on the tab.

Comment: Thanks marking... I have modified answer.. so please remove down vote if possible.

Comment: can you repost the hasClass please was interesting

Comment: I have reposted... if you like my answer please mark as correct and give upvote

Answer (score 1):

For handling situation like "If the class `special` is present in current document, then remove `tab_item` and add `tab_item_color` instead"; you can do following thing:

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('.special').length > 0) //checking count of DOM element with class special
  {
    $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item").addClass("tab_item_color");
  }
});
```

```css
.tab_item {
  background: none;
}
.tab_item_color {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="special">div with special class</div>

<div class="tab_item">div 1</div>
<div class="tab_item">div 2</div>
<div class="tab_item">div 3</div>
```